# How to manage html webs after upload file to servlet?

Tags: java, html, web-applications

I am developing a web application in which I have an Index.jsp with a form to upload a file to the servlet:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
  import="com.uteva.AppWebNieve.ProcesadoExcel"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" lang="es" xml:lang="es">

      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-
        8859-1">
          <title>AppWebInformesNieve</title>
       </meta>
  </head>
     <body>


      <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
         <input type="file" name="file" />
           <input value="Subir Excel" type="submit" />
        </form>

          </body>
       </html>
```

Then I upload correctly the file with my java class:

```
            @Override
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest 
              request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
           IOException{
         //***************AQUI MANEJAMOS LA SUBIDA DEL FICHERO LINCES DE INCIDENCIAS***********************
        // Get the file location where it would be stored.
          //String filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");            
          boolean isMultipart;      
          int maxFileSize = 10000 * 1024;
          int maxMemSize = 1000 * 1024;
          File file ;
         // Check that we have a file upload request
          isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
          if( !isMultipart ){   //No se ha podido subir el fichero
             /*out.println("<html>");
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
             out.println("</head>");
             out.println("<body>");
             out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
             out.println("</body>");
             out.println("</html>");*/
             return;
          }
          DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
          // maximum size that will be stored in memory
          factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
          // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
          factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

          // Create a new file upload handler
          ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
          // maximum file size to be uploaded.
          upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

          try{ 
          // Parse the request to get file items.
          List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

          // Process the uploaded file items
          Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

          out.println("<html>");
          out.println("<head>");
          out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");           
          out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
          while ( i.hasNext () ) 
          {
             FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
             if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
             {
                // Get the uploaded file parameters
                String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                String fileName = fi.getName();
                String contentType = fi.getContentType();
                boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                // Write the file
                if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
                   file = new File( filename + 
                   fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                }else{
                   file = new File( filename + 
                   fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                }
                fi.write( file ) ;
                out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
                System.out.println("Fichero "+filename+" subido correctamente al servidor!!");
             }
          }
          out.println("</body>");
          out.println("</html>");
       }catch(Exception ex) {
           System.out.println(ex);
       }
       }
```

But after uploading, this open a new simple html which is built in the previously java method by out.println...

The point is, how I can manage this upload to stay in the same html knowing whether the file has been uploaded or not to do some other things with this file? I cannot use get method to upload files and let form action blank...

Or, opening a new html, there must be another way for make a more complex html than using out.println in Java function....

thanks.

Comment: I think I need to use Javascript to upload the file

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it using AJAX following this tutorial: http://www.programming-free.com/2013/06/ajax-file-upload-java-iframe.html